# How to add newDataValidation() code block into my Google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-macros

So I have a block of code under the `OnEdit(e)` trigger. I have identified the range and it is working. The problem is I am now trying to add some data validation using apps script on that same range.

I have a block of code written out but I am unsure how to implement it properly on the desired range. I am currently using `onOpen(e)` and am also unsure if it is acting on the correct column as the data validation does not work when I run the code despite the REGEXMATCH expression being correct.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Formatting the content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to change the `background color` and `apply data validation` only to the `column B` of a sheet called `TermList`. If that's the case:

- The code that is creating the data validation is correct. As it is now, it should create a new data validation when you open the file. Actually, I would not include this in an `onOpen` trigger because you only need to create the data validation once, not every time you open the file.
- In the following line you are comparing a [Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) to a `string`, something which can never return `true`. You should apply [getName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getname) to the sheet. This might be the reason you think the data validation is not being properly inserted:

```
  if(sheet != 'TermList' && col != 2) return
```

- You are also using [offset(0, 0)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offset(Integer,Integer)) for no reason (the range returned by this method is the one to which this method is applied, because you are not offsetting any row nor column).
- If you want to change the background only if the sheet name is `TermList` and the edited column is B, then you should change this:

```
  if(sheet != 'TermList' && col != 2) return;
  var color = e.value;
  range.offset(0, 0).setBackground(color);
```

To this:

```
  if (sheet.getName() == 'TermList' && col == 2) {
    var color = e.value;
    range.setBackground(color);
  }
```

I hope this is of any help.